# width: 100% with position: absolute

Tags: css, width, css-position

If you do:

```
<div style="width: auto; background: red; color: white">test</div>
```

You get a div that is stretched to fill the entire screen width (100%). That is what I need to happen.

However, I also need the starting position to be set. So, I need `position: absolute`.

When I add position:absolute, the width of the `div` is only as wide as the content within (similar to floats). Is there any way around this?

I cannot simply specify `width: 100%` since this does not take in to account border sizes, etc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> When I add position:absolute, the width of the div is only as wide as
>   the content within.. (Similar to floats). Is there any way around
>   this?
>
> I cannot simply specify width:100% since this does not take in to
>   account border sizes, etc..

You could use `position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0`.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/yQWGV/

Comment: Almost good, but if you need scrollbars (add `overflow: auto`) then you'll loose the padding on the right (content will go up to the scrollbar and ignore your padding)

Comment: @outofmind: Try a `box-sizing: border-box;` based solution instead. If that doesn't work, provide a demo showing the problem.

Comment: `box-sizing` had no effect. See the [jsfiddle for a demo of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/yQWGV/342/)

Comment: @outofmind: Adding `word-wrap: break-word;`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/yQWGV/343/. If that's no good, what should happen instead?

Comment: Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/dzwmomLh/10/ - this way the div doesn't use 100% of the width, the border of the caption is too short. When you make the table visible (display:normal), the padding right to the table is visible (table has 20px to the scrollbar) - when you use inline-grid instead of inline-block, the width of the div is 100%, the caption border is on the complete width, but there's no padding right to the table. What I need: 100% width for the caption plus padding right to the overflown table

Answer (score 3):

You can use width:100% and the css attribute box-sizing, to get the box model working like IE 5.5, i.e. padding and border counted into the width.

```
div.absolute {
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    background-color: #F00;
    position: absolute; top: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dJtm2/

Be wary though, as it's a relatively new CSS3 attribute and will only work in newer browsers, and as you can see from my example requires the dreadful counter-productive measure that is vendor prefixes.

Comment: Almost good, but if you need scrollbars (add `overflow: auto`) then you'll loose the padding on the right (content will go up to the scrollbar and ignore your padding)

Answer (score 2):

simply write like this:

```
div.absolute {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    background-color: #F00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    padding: 50px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dJtm2/1/

in this `padding & border` not increase the width of the element.

Comment: Almost good, but if you need scrollbars (add `overflow: auto`) then you'll loose the padding on the right (content will go up to the scrollbar and ignore your padding)